# how to skip gradle asking about new APIs?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

recently I've upgraded gradle wrapper on my java project from 7.2 to 8.2 and now the command `./gradlew init --type pom --dsl groovy` became interactive and asks the following question:

> Generate build using new APIs and behavior (some features may change in the next minor release)? (default: no) [yes, no]

This broke my scripts that use this command :(
is there any command line option to automatically choose `no` and make the command non-interactive again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand the gradle init doc, there is no such option for now, but you may use this simple workaround:

```bash
echo 'no' | ./gradlew init --type pom --dsl groovy
```

Comment: thanks!!!! I assumed that gradle reads from console, not from stdin and didn't try such simple thing ;-] it seems I'm a man of a low faith, ha ha ;-)

Comment: btw: `./gradlew init --type pom --dsl groovy <<< 'no'` is probably a tiny bit faster ;-)